# Odoo: How to override JS function in website-frontend (e.g. function payment_transaction_poll_status in module website_sale.validate)?

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-9

As an example, please take a look at this Odoo JS module:
https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/addons/website_sale/static/src/js/website_sale_validate.js

It's basically:

```
odoo.define('website_sale.validate', function(require) {
    "use strict";
    ...
    $(document).ready(function () {
        ...
        function payment_transaction_poll_status() {...}
        payment_transaction_poll_status();
    });
});
```

Let's say I wanted to create an own app "test". JS is located at /test/static/src/js/test.js - everything fine thus far.

In there, I want to override *payment_transaction_poll_status*.

Usually, to work with another module, I'd do this:

```
odoo.define('test.test', function (require) {
    "use strict";
    var website_sale_validate = require('website_sale.validate');
    website_sale_validate.include({...});
});
```

But even that (without overriding anything) leads to:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'include' of undefined

(the Odoo app *website_sale* is installed and *website_sale_validate.js* can be found via Chrome dev tools)

Furthermore, I think one cannot override functions inside a module that doesn't even export anything. Right?

For now I conclude that it is not possible to override a function of an Odoo module in the given case. Am I correct?

Is there a way to override *payment_transaction_poll_status*?

Thanks in advance!